# How can i change tab with button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
Tabs = ttk.Notebook(main)
Tabs.pack(side = "top", expand = 1, fill = "both", padx = 10, pady = 10)



tab1 = ttk.Frame(Tabs)
Tabs.add(tab1, text = "Registration")
tab2 = ttk.Frame(Tabs)
Tabs.add(tab2, text = "All Students")
tab3 = ttk.Frame(Tabs)
Tabs.add(tab3, text = "Lectures")

def newtab():
    #open tab2


b1 = Button(tab1, text = "show tab2", command = newtab)
b1.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

So this my code, and what i wanna do is that when b1 is clicke for it to go to tab2 itselfe.

p.s i tried ttk.Notebook.select(tab2) and it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a `ttk.Notebook` instance to use `select(tab_id)`.
In your code,Use

```
def newtab():
    Tabs.select(tab2) # should be a instance of ttk.Notebook.
```

Comment: A typo,my fault.